# javascript Arrays to mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, explode

I have a file called **translations.js**, this js does got have two vars. This **two vars** are containing **over 20.000 words**.

> var english = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", ...]
>
> var farsi = ["translation1", "translation2", "translation3",
>   "translation3"]

So i want to add all the values to a table on mySQL.

How can I do that quick and good? I want to do this with PHP.

I have the table "**translations**", containing this columns: *id, english, farsi*.

I want that all the words should be added into the database. So i thought to split this file into english.js and farsi.js - after that I wanted to use "explode" on both variables, foreach till no "" is there and then i wanted to add them step by step.

Is there a easier way? Does this way make sense?

Thank you!

Comment: You're probably best off just using php for this. First, transform the two arrays into a map, so that you get  `word1 : translation1` pairs. You could either have the javascript generate this map, save the map to a text file, then open that file with php. Or you could read the .js files into your php and chop them up there. Or you could use your own suggestion of looping over both arrays. Then you just make a connection with php to your database and use a standard `insert into`.

Answer (score 0):

If those arrays are  valid json by themselves you could make a json file for each and read the file using `file_get_contents()`, then use `json_decode()` to convert to php array.

Loop over array to do inserts.

Alternative would be to load those variables into an html page and use ajax to post the whole array to php script. Loop over array received in $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Does have `english` array and `farsi` array exactly the same size?
(I suppose yes).

Maybe you can create a file `english.json` and a `farsi.json`;

each file must only contains `["word1", "word2", "word3"]` so remove `var english =`.

then use

```
$listEnglish = json_decode(file_get_contents('path_to_english.json'));
$listFarsi   = json_decode(file_get_contents('path_to_farsi.json'));
```

It should generate a php array for each one.

finally loop on it

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($listEnglish); $i++)
{
    $englishWord = $listEnglish[$i];
    $farsiWord   = $listFarsi[$i];

    //Then you insert
    INSERT INTO translation(english, farsi) VALUES ($englishWord, $farsiWord);
}
```

Comment: Sometime its faster to do some things manually than with a script =) (unless the file is too big to be open with a text editor)

Comment: Did it, but its loading and loading and i'm not able to see just 5 pieces. I tried it to just to echo for($i = 0; 5; $i++) - And im getting timeouts.

Comment: Sorry i was in week-end. I did a test and it works for me. I've a test folder containing 2 files. First one is `english.json` containing `["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"]`, second one is `test.php` with only `<?php $listEnglish = json_decode(file_get_contents('./english.json'));?>` and if I var_dump $listEnglish I have my array `array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "word1" [1]=> string(5) "word2" [2]=> string(5) "word3" [3]=> string(5) "word4" } `. Are you sure the path is the good one ? Is your json file correctly filled ?